# Why can't I code sign this Mac app?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, code-signing, mac-app-store

I started some days ago a small Mac app for Mac OS X Lion. I've never uploaded a Mac app before, so this is the very first time.

This is what I've already done:

- Created App ID
- Created Certificate
- Installed Certificate
- Created a Production Provisioning Profile
- Changed the App ID to my generated one
- Created a new Configuration based on "Release"
- Changed its Code Signing to 3rd Party Mac Developer Application
- Selected the "Production"-Configuration which I created for the Archive-Scheme
- Archived the Application

Now I wanted to "Share" the Application. Xcode (4.1 btw) said to me, there were no valid signing identities. Does I need to add an Entitlement.plist like in iOS? Have I forgotten something?

---

**Update:**

I just figured out, that I have to sign my app twice. I've still selected "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" but I can't select the Installer cert while submitting my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I deleted my App and created it new.

I didn't create a new Configuration, and I only changed the Code Signing Indentity of the Target to 3rd Party Mac Developer Application. After this, I archived the app and then I was able to select the installer cert.

Comment: in the config, i have the code sign right, but when i archive my application and want to share it i can only choose identity dont sign... was this also your problem?

Comment: yes, i now figured out, that i need 2 certificates... one to sign the app, one to sign the package

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the WWDR intermediate certificate? I just had the exact same problems and my issue was that the intermediate certificate was not installed on my machine. Granted, nowhere does Apple explicitly say you need it installed, more like suggestions. But, you do need it. You can find it [here](http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer), or by going to Developer Certificate Utility under the Mac Developer Center.

Comment: By the way, if this is the problem, you'll need to restart Xcode after installing the intermediate certificate so that Xcode recognizes it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already some iOS Apps live on the App Store and the WWDR certificate is the same. The problem must be somewhere else.